# Duplicate Record Issue in odoo

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have added new custom field in sale order line and invoice line and then I have override a method called `action_invoice_create()` that triggers when user click on a button.

What I am trying to get from this method is output like so:

```
order_line SR
order_line ZRE
invoice_line SR
invoice_line ZRE
```

but currently I get this output that show duplicated record:

```
order_line SR
invoice_line SR
invoice_line SR
order_line ZRE
invoice_line ZRE
invoice_line ZRE
```

So I need a help to correct the for loops to get the correct output.

```py
class SalesOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    _description = 'Move VAT Code'

    @api.multi
    def action_invoice_create(self, grouped=False, final=False):
        res = super(SalesOrder, self).action_invoice_create()
        for record in self:
            for rec in record.order_line:
              print('order_line %s' % rec.x_vat_code_id.name)
              for invoice in record.invoice_ids:
                for invoice_line in invoice.invoice_line_ids:
                    invoice_line['vat_code_id'] = rec.x_vat_code_id.id
                    print('invoice_line %s' % rec.x_vat_code_id.name)

        return res
```

Data Format:

```
{'order_line': [(0, 0, {'state': 'draft', 'x_qty': 0.0, 'x_partner': False, 'x_price_unit': 0.0, 'x_onhand': 0.0, 'x_reverse': 0.0, 'x_reference': False, 'x_stock_partner': False, 'x_vat_code_id': 51})]}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with odoo, but posting the data shape in your question would help answering the question.

Comment: please check the data format @vekerdyb

Answer (score 0):

You can just unintend the loop which iterates over record.invoice_ids like this and check whether it works fine or not.

```
class SalesOrder(models.Model):
_inherit = 'sale.order'
_description = 'Move VAT Code'

@api.multi
def action_invoice_create(self, grouped=False, final=False):
    res = super(SalesOrder, self).action_invoice_create()
    for record in self:
        for rec in record.order_line:
          print('order_line %s' % rec.x_vat_code_id.name)
        for invoice in record.invoice_ids:
          for invoice_line in invoice.invoice_line_ids:
              invoice_line['vat_code_id'] = rec.x_vat_code_id.id
              print('invoice_line %s' % rec.x_vat_code_id.name)

    return res
```

Comment: order_line SR
order_line ZRE
invoice_line ZRE
invoice_line ZRE   still getting duplicated value

Comment: Can you share what is stored into self, ie, record?

Comment: check the the question above , record is posted

Comment: There is only details about one order line in the question, afaik there should be two based on your desired output.

Comment: @ Mihran Thalhath you are correct,, it is just a demo,

Comment: You can easily view the values stored in self if you have a debugger running on an IDE like PyCharm

Comment: I am new to programming and I am using pycharm ..so how to debug it